# Error while installing opsycopg2, gunicorn, dj-database-url, dj-static, tatic3 (heroku getting started with django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

(python version - 3.4.1, Windows 8.1 64 bit, Microsoft visual C++ 10)
 I am getting the error below trying to install django-toolbelt using pip. btw i am a beginner and just starting with out working with django. I have been looking around for any solution online but nothing has worked for me yet. I have tried setting the path and reinstalled visual c++ as well although i as unable to find vsvars64 or vsvarsall anywhere in the tools folder.

```
**$ pip install django-toolbelt**
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-toolbelt in c:
python34\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in c:\python34
lib\site-packages (from django-toolbelt)
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2 (from django-toolbelt)
Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\Ekwinder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Ekwinde
\psycopg2\setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2

Downloading/unpacking gunicorn (from django-toolbelt)
Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url (from django-toolbelt)
Downloading dj_database_url-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking dj-static (from django-toolbelt)
Downloading dj-static-0.0.6.tar.gz
Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\Ekwinder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Ekwinde
\dj-static\setup.py) egg_info for package dj-static

Downloading/unpacking static3 (from dj-static->django-toolbelt)
Downloading static3-0.5.1.tar.gz
Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\Ekwinder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Ekwinde
\static3\setup.py) egg_info for package static3

Installing collected packages: psycopg2, gunicorn, dj-database-url, dj-static,
tatic3
Running setup.py install for psycopg2
Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Ekwinder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Ekwinder\psycopg2\se
up.py", line 581, in <module>
ext_modules=ext)
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.4.1-py3.4.egg\setuptools
command\install.py", line 61, in run
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 554, in run
self.run_command('build')
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 348, in run
self.build_extensions()
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 457, in build
extensions
self.build_extension(ext)
File "C:\Users\Ekwinder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Ekwinder\psycopg2\se
up.py", line 285, in build_extension
build_ext.build_extension(self, extension)
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 512, in build
extension
depends=ext.depends)
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
self.initialize()
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initializ

vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcv
rsall
raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: ['path']
Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools,
okenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Ekwinder\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_Ekwinder
\psycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).rea
().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Ekwinde
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-p1a28xcn-record\install-record.txt --single-version-ext
rnally-managed --compile:
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

copying lib\psycopg1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

copying lib\_json.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

copying lib\_range.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\dbapi20_tpc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\testconfig.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\testutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_bugX000.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_bug_gc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_cancel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_connection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_copy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_cursor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_dates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests



copying tests\test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tes
s

copying tests\test_green.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_lobject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_notify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\test

copying tests\test_quote.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_transaction.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_types_basic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_types_extras.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\test_with.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

copying tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\psycopg2\tests

Skipping implicit fixer: buffer

Skipping implicit fixer: idioms

Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal

Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma

running build_ext

building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension

Traceback (most recent call last):



File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\Ekwinder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Ekwinder\psycopg2\setup.
y", line 581, in <module>

    ext_modules=ext)



File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.4.1-py3.4.egg\setuptools\com
and\install.py", line 61, in run

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 554, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 348, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 457, in build_ext
nsions

    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "C:\Users\Ekwinder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Ekwinder\psycopg2\setup.
y", line 285, in build_extension

    build_ext.build_extension(self, extension)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 512, in build_ext
nsion

    depends=ext.depends)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile

    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsa
l

    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: ['path']

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Us
rs\\Ekwinder\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_Ekwinder\\psycopg2\\setup.py';exe
(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
 __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Ekwinder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
1a28xcn-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Ekwinder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Ekwi
der\psycopg2
Storing debug log for failure in c:/Users/Ekwinder\pip\pip.log
Ekwinder@STARGATE ~/hellodjango/venv
$ :
```

Comment: Is it the full version of Visual Studio, or the Express? Also, do you have the 64-bit version?

Comment: @sHtev well, it is express and anyway i learned that gunicorn is not compatible with windows or something like that. Shifted over to Linux for django development